# Mathematical formulation for maximum sum of edge weights

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, summation

For my academic research purposes, I have a situation as below.

The initial problem looks as in below figure.[image: Initial Problem query]

I need to find one match for each of P1,P2,P3 from the right side such that the sum of edge weights is maximized. If we look at a solution for the below query, the solution can be as below.
[image: An answer to the question]

If we consider the sum of edge weights now, it is

- P1 -> A1 (1.5)
- P2 -> A2 (1.9)
- P3 -> A3 (2)

And the total would be 5.4 which is the maximum. How can I represent the above problem in the form of a mathematical equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the two sets $P$ and $A$ indexed with $i$ and $j$, respectively, I would use a binary variable $x_{ij}$ which is equal to 1 iff I select the edge from $i \in P$ to $j \in A$.

I want to maximize the sum of the edges' weights, subject to the constraints that there are no two edges incident to the same node. As I understand, all nodes in $P$ must have a match, while some nodes in $A$ may not have a match (of course, the cardinality of $P$ must be smaller or equal to the cardinality of $A$):

$$ \max \sum_{i \in P}\sum_{j \in A} x_{ij} \cdot w_{ij} \;\;s.t.$$

$$\sum_{j \in A} x_{ij} = 1\;\;\;\forall i\in P$$

$$\sum_{i \in P} x_{ij} \leq 1\;\;\;\forall j\in A$$

$$x_{ij} \in \{0,1\}$$

where $w_{ij}$ is the weight of the edge from $i$ to $j$.

The first constraint ensures that the degree of each node in $P$ is exactly 1 (all nodes in $P$ have only one incident edge), while the second constraint ensures that each node in $A$ has at most one incident edge.

Hope I correctly understood the question.

Comment: thanks for your response. However, I can not always guarantee the set P has a match in A. So there can be cases where a particular vertex from P can still be empty.

Comment: It should be enough to change the = with $\leq$ in the first constraint. Please, accept the answer if it is satisfactory for you.